# simple contract to contract interaction

Tags: solidity, contract-design

Please help me!

Lets say I have two contracts deployed at different times in solidity in mist-wallet:

```
contract E{
    address public sender;
    uint public x;

    function set(uint _x) {
        x = _x;
        sender = msg.sender;
    }

    function get() constant returns(uint) {
        sender = msg.sender;
        return x;
    }
}
```

and say the address is 0x98789aD9797ad908097ad9870987DDD97897aD (this is a made up address by the way)

Now I want to have another contract to communicate with E and manipulate the x parameter from time to time

```
contract F {
    uint public x;
    address addressE = 0x98789aD9797ad908097ad9870987DDD97897aD ;
    address public sender;

    function F() {
    }

    function setE(uint num) returns(bool) {
         x=num;
        return addressE.callcode('set(uint256)', num);
    }

    function getE() returns(uint) {
        return ?????????????;  /*  WHAT DO I PUT HERE? */
    }

}
```

In the `getE()` function, what code do I put so it can get value of x from `addressE`?

please let me know, thanks
sorry if this is a very simple question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you asked for simple, I thought I'd simplify.

Contract E is compiled and deployed separately. I added an event log to make it easier to see what's happening (e.g. in Remix).

```
contract E {
  uint public x;

  event LogUpdate(uint newXValue);

  function set(uint _x) public returns(bool success) {
    x = _x;
    LogUpdate(x);
    return true;
  }

}
```

Now you want to deploy a second contract that will talk to it. Since you know the interface, you can do that.

You can do it this way:

```
return addressE.call(bytes4(sha3('set(uint256)')), num);
```

On grounds of readability, I would avoid that unless the following can't work for some reason.

In the *second* source file (with F), describe the *interface* to "E".

```
contract EInterface {
    uint public x;
    function set(uint _x) returns(bool success) {} 
}
```

And let the compiler sort out the function signatures:

```
EInterface e = EInterface(addressE);
```

There will a thing called "e" of type EInterface which is an EInterface located at addressE (where addressE is the address of previously deployed contract).

Call the functions with ease:

```
return e.set(num);
return e.x();
```

Make life easy, and pass E's address into F's constructor.

```
function F(address EAddress)
```

In a single source file to simplify rudimentary testing.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.6;

// Compile and deploy E by itself. 

contract E {

    uint public x;

    event LogUpdate(uint newXValue);

    function set(uint _x) public returns(bool success) {
        x = _x;
        LogUpdate(x);
        return true;
    }

}

// These go in one source file.
// The compiler can "see" the E Interface as it compiles F.

contract EInterface {
    uint public x;
    function set(uint _x) returns(bool success) {} // undefined function is part of the "Interface". 
}

contract F {

    address addressE;

    // E is already deployed.
    // Conveniently pass E's address to F

    function F(address EAddress) {
        addressE = EAddress;
    }

    function setE(uint num) public returns(bool) {
        // valid ... 
        // return addressE.call(bytes4(sha3('set(uint256)')), num);
        EInterface e = EInterface(addressE); // "EInterface" is understood from interface code above.
        return e.set(num);
    }

    function getE() public constant returns(uint E) {
        EInterface e = EInterface(addressE);
        return e.x();  /*  WHAT DO I PUT HERE? */
    }

}
```

In Remix to show it working.

Create E

[image]

Create F, Set X

[image]

Get X

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much Rob!  Yes it helped very much.

Now I'm wondering, what if the uint in contract E you don't want it to be public, but protected where only a few contracts can access it, like contract F.

How would you set this up?

Comment: Thanks for working example! Your answer should get more upvotes.